# multi series Fusion chart using php ,string xml and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml

```
$strXMLxx .= "<categories>\n";
$strXMLxx .= "<category label='". $arr2[1] ."'/>\n";
$strXMLxx .= "</categories>\n"; 
$strXMLxx .= "<dataset seriesname='abc'>\n";
$strXMLxx .= "<set value='" .$BOY. "' />\n";
$strXMLxx .= "</dataset>\n";
$strXMLxx .= "<trendlines>\n";
$strXMLxx .= "<line startvalue='12250' color='#0075c2'    displayvalue='Previous{br}Average' valueonright='1' thickness='1'  showbelow='1' tooltext='Previous year quarterly target : $13.5K' />\n";
$strXMLxx .= "</trendlines>";
```

I try to store a value in `$strXMLxx` to use it for drawing a chart:

```
<?
     $strXML = "<chart caption='".$r3."' subCaption='' canvaspadding='5'  placeValuesInside='1' rotateValues='1' slantLabels='1' labelDisplay='ROTATE'  pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1'  xaxisname='".$tbl_header."' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix='' basefont='tahoma' basefontsize='10' basefontcolor='#000000' >"
     .$strXMLxx;
      $strXML .= "</chart>";
?>
```

After execution this message appears `:No data to display`